# New website or a feature in the current website

Tags: software-development, product-management, user-experience-design

I am new to project management. I work for a social media website with over a million users. As an initial project, I have been asked to research and design a new feature and best way to increase user base for it.

The thing is I am unable to decide if I should make a website with a new domain for that feature, or should I make something within the original domain itself.

The benefit of creating a new website is that I get complete control and can do a lot of experiments. That's good for my learning.

But at the same time, the purpose of this new feature is also to increase our existing user base in website.

What do you think is the best way to go about it? Any suggestions/recommended readings will be useful.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! This question is not about project management within the scope defined in our help center. In addition, it is too broad and largely an opinion poll. Q&A sites are not suitable for exploring ideas or open-ended questions, even when the questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a really good business case for rolling out a separate website that will benefit your employer (it sounds like currently your only reason is for your personal learning), then I would suggest making it a feature in the existing website.

The existing website has all its plumbing already taken care of, whereas if you were to roll out a new website, you'd waste a lot of time on that (which, if I understand your role correctly, isn't going to benefit your project management experience all that much).

Also, I wouldn't underestimate the learning experience inherent in building a new feature in an existing website with over a million users - you get to focus on the feature without having to worry about plumbing, and all those users will give you instant feedback (assuming you know how to analyse their usage effectively). That's golden.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a new domain, there is a huge risk that you'll take traffic from the old one. Therefore, I'm not sure if it is the right move.

You can however have controlled experiment in existing services (or web pages) with A/B testing. If you have that user base your company should have something that allows teams experimenting with new features. If you don't, have a look at [feature switches](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html), because it is a good start for things you would like to do.